# Turn off the leading * in C# block comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, block-comments

In the following thread...

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232323/asterisks-in-multi-line-comments

...*person27* shows how to turn off the extra asterisk that is placed, automatically, by Visual Studio.  Unfortunately, in VS2013, this option doesn't seem to be available any longer.

Does anyone know - is there still some hidden method for doing this?

To clarify further:

[image]

Comment: It's in VS2017. What version do you have?

Comment: It's in VS2015 as well. Given that `person27` said it was in 2012 (I can't check) I'd be surprised if it wasn't in VS2013 as well. Are you absolutely sure you looked in the right place?

Comment: This feature had to be completely redone in VS2015 due to the Roslyn integration.  VS2015 first shipped with it being completely unavailable, unfinished work, it took an Update to get it back.  At that time it also added the option to disable it with Tools > Options, somewhat necessary since users got used to it not being done.  VS2013 just doesn't have the option, and never will.

Comment: Whelp that answered that one. I guess I'm not that surprised after all, typical Microsoft.

Comment: @HansPassant: I see. Hopefully we're getting 2017 shortly...  However, this is *public* sector, so I won't hold my breath. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

That is for readbility purpopse, anyway, if you are worry about it, simply go to

`Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Uncheck "Insert * at the start of new lines when writing /**/ comments"`

This is working for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. It can be related to a Professional/Community version.

Comment: Did you read the other thread that OP linked to? He's aware of this option and says he doesn't have it.

Comment: I haven't, sorry. Anyway this is suppose to exists also in VS2013, can it be a community/professional version thing?

Comment: That sounds like a better guess, yes. I'm waiting for OP to clarify exactly what version they have since they don't state that in the question.

Comment: @Equalsk: I'm using 2013 Pro.

Comment: @Nekeniehl: Unfortunately, I don't find this as readable as clear rows of comments (which we use in documentation). At the end of the day, our organisation uses Visual Studio, we don't need this particular thing ramming down our throats.

Comment: Did you try to search it in the search Field? maybe it was move from there to another place in VS2013, I'm sorry I cannot help you as I don't have this version.
Search for something meaning, like "comments" and check one by one.

Comment: @Paul Okey, last option, Could you try? 

`Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Generate XML documentation comments for ///` and uncheck it.

Comment: @Nekeniehl: See HansPassant's comments under the OP.

Comment: @Nekeniehl: Thanks for your input, I do appreciate your looking.